# How can I get boto to generate signed URLs for S3 that trigger downloads?

Tags: boto

I've attempted this:

```
connection = S3Connection(
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

url = connection.generate_url(
    60,
    'GET',
    settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
    self.get_object().image,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

but when I try to visit the signed URL I get this message:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

If I remove the `headers` attribute on the other hand, I can access the image just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you can't set arbitrary headers using generate_url, and while the `response_headers` option exists AWS also has limited options as to what you can set. This will do what's expected in this case.

```
url = connection.generate_url(
    60,
    'GET',
    settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
    self.get_object().image,
    response_headers={
        'response-content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
    })
```